# C++ variable can be accessed in constructor, but not in function

Tags: c++, function, variables, constructor

So I've come across this weird problem where I have an object, which has a pointer to another object, and of that object I want to access a variable. I can do that in the constructor, but it doesn't work when I'm in a function.

http://pastebin.com/2FHd7ak0

EDIT:
The variable 'state' of the blocks seems to change after I initalized them. At first it outputs 0x3015a8, then it changes to 0x110000

Edit2: so I've made a small example which compiles, but it gives me an access violation return code. Im clearly doing something wrong with pointers, but I cant find out what... I come from Java, so that might be a reason for it.

http://pastebin.com/uF8t8wx9

Comment: AHHHH!!! [Variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) gone bad! :)

Comment: I don't see how this code can compile because you access `bar->var` before the full definition of `Bar`. When I put the definition of `Bar` ahead of `Foo`, remove the nested class forward declaration of `Bar` from `Foo`, and add a `main`, it compiles, links and produces the expected results.

Comment: Also, you are familiar with C#, right? In C++, you'd best avoid things like `new anything()` as a function parameter.

Comment: As far as I can tell, except for `Bar` being an incomplete type when used, the above should work fine (i.e.: if `Bar` is actually properly declared, before `Foo` is).

Comment: @Mystical You mean with the this->bar = bar? When I change that in my code it still does not work. At Mr Lister: I am familiar with Java yes, and am fairly new to C++. At Mark B: It isn't fully functional C++ code in this state, but imagine it being in a main function. Also, I don't access bar->var before the definition of bar, as I wait first before making an instance of Foo.

Comment: @Mysticial: Does variable shadowing ever go good? ;v)

Comment: "The constructor works nicely". No it doesn't. The constructor won't compile. Please provide an actual program Note that we don't want *the* real code, we want *some* real code. Please add `int main` to create an actual program, so that we can talk about actual compiler error messages. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: @Gmfreaky : "I don't access bar->var before the definition." Yes, you do. In this case "before" means "at an earlier line in the file", not "at an earlier time during execution."

Comment: *Aside*: there is no reason to have **both** `#include "StateGame.h"` and `class StateGame;`. It doesn't hurt, it just doesn't do any good and is distracting.

Comment: What is the type of `state->camX`? Regardless, there is no reason that your program should exit in the code that you have shown. Please add `<<std::endl` to each of the logging lines and re-run your test. I suspect that you will see more data.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of problems with your sample program:

1. In the definition of `Foo::Foo`, you have this expression: `bar->var`. At this point in your program, type `Bar` is incomplete. You cannot dereference a pointer to an incomplete type.
2. You declare two types with similar names: first `::Foo::Bar` and then later `::Bar`. I suspect that you meant for them to be the same type. They aren't.
3. In your main code fragment, you have this expression: `new Foo(new Bar());`. This won't compile, because `Foo` does not have a constructor which takes a `Bar*`. (It does have a constructor which takes a `Foo::Bar*`, but that's a different beast.)

---

*Note*: You have now posted fragments of some other program. None of the problems I list above are present in this other program.

---

In your [pastebin entry](http://pastebin.com/2FHd7ak0), you never initialize `StateGame::blockArray`. You dereference it in `stateGame::setBlock`. This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I just posted the actual program, so you might want to look at that for more information about the problem.

Comment: @Gmfreaky - with respect, I must disagree. You did not post the actual program. You posted *part* of an actual program. Please reduce your sample program to the smallest possible program that still demonstrates the erorr, and post that **short**, **complete** program in its entirety. See: http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Okay, I've summarized the thing here: http://pastebin.com/2FHd7ak0 if there is still something missing or if it's too much, please tell me.

Comment: Oh, I see something I haven't noticed before: the output of 'state' changes from 0x3000c4 to 0x110000 which is really odd, since I don't delete the 'state' from Block... as far as I know. So somehow it changes the state variable.

Comment: @Gmfreaky - your pastebin entry is incomplete, **way** too long, and doesn't compile. I really can't effectively help you if you won't reduce your program to a [**short, self-contained, complete example**](http://sscce.org). In the meanwhile, I did notice that you never initialize the `blockArray` variable; that *might* cause the problems you are seeing.

Comment: So I've reduced the code a ton, and I've tested and compiled it.. it now gives some Access Violation return code (0xC0000005), so I'm clearly messing up something with pointers... I am new to C++ (I mainly use Java). You can find the compiling and semi-functioning code here: http://pastebin.com/uF8t8wx9

Answer (score 0):

At any method in `Foo`, `Bar` hasn't been defined (only forward declared) when defining the member function. Thus accessing `Bar::var` is illegal. If the compiler lets you go away with it, it's mere luck, but it's not obliged to this.

Move the definition of `Bar` before the definition of `Foo` and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

You pass in a `StateGame` to the `Block::Block` constructor. Almost certainly you then destroy the `StateGame` object after you construct the `Block`s (Perhaps StateGame exists on the stack or you `delete`d it).

Comment: I don't think so, because the StateGame continues existing in my gameloop. I never call delete on it.